# How do I set up SSO between ASP.NET application and Sharepoint 2019 Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, single-sign-on, http-status-code-401

I have an ASP.NET application which has to display search results from SharePoint 2019 which is installed on another server.

The ASP.NET application has the Windows Authentication turned on and I want to use these credentials for authentication against the SharePoint.

I use the following code to get the search results from SharePoint:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
})
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var requri = new Uri("https://sharepoint.mydomain.com.pl/_api/search/query");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requri);
    }
}
```

This works as long as the ASP.NET application is hosted on IIS Express during the debugging in Visual Studio.

But as soon as I host the application on the IIS server I get the 401 Unauthorized response from SharePoint.

What am I missing? How do I set up my application and/or SharePoint to get this to work?

Comment: In general, passing through Windows Authentication like that is so difficult that you shouldn't attempt it, it's called "impersonation". Instead, get yourself authorized to do things with Sharepoint via an API token (I'm assuming that's possible, I haven't worked with Sharepoint in years)

Comment: @mason Could you give mi some hints how should I acquire that token. Please note I'm using Sharepoint on-prem 2019.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much about Sharepoint. I googled "Sharepoint API token" and [this seems promising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints). I think you could have searched and found that just as easily as I could...